# NUMPY create, fill with random binary data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to create an 2D array.

```
    import numpy as np
    self.col = 10
    self.row = 5

    ...

    matrix = np.array(self.row, self.col) # NOT WORKING
```

What is the right syntax please

i also need to fill it with random binary data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generate a random matrix with binary values:

```
import numpy as np
row, col = 10, 5
matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=(row,col))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

def toBit(x):
        if x<= 0:
            x = 0               
        else:
            x = 1
        return x

VtoBit = np.vectorize(toBit)

arr1 = np.random.randn(6,10)
arr2 = VtoBit(arr1)

print(arr2)
```

Comment: What is the benefit, if any, of your approach to that specified in the accepted answer for seven years ago?